# CSS vertical menu on two sides

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a design with two vertical menus on each side of the main content part. 
I tried various combinations of inline and relative and fixed positions but can't get it to work.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g4vbampm/3/

The menus (red and blue blocks) should be right next to the middle green part (position:fixed put it at the edge of the screen to the left). They should also start at the top of the screen and never move. The height of the middle green part is going to change dynamically with js code.

```css
.app {
  text-align: center;
}
.left {
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.center {
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">

  <div class="left">
    menu1
    <br/>menu2
    <br/>menu3
    <br/>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    CONTENT
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a

    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>a
    <br/>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    menu1
    <br/>menu2
    <br/>menu3
    <br/>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The menus (red and blue blocks) should be right next to the middle green part (position:fixed put it at the edge of the screen to the left). They should also start at the top of the screen and never move.

If they should “never move,” then you want `position:fixed` (unless you want to constantly adapt the position via JavaScript, which is in most cases bad in terms of performance and visual outcome.)

Fixed positioning always takes the viewport as reference point. But you can still use it here, if you calculate the position dynamically.

Your middle element is 300px wide, so the other two elements need to be positioned at 50% + 150px, from the right resp. left (the opposite in each case.)

```
.left,
.right {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.left{
  background:red;
  width:150px;
  height:300px;
  right: calc(50% + 150px);
}
.right{
  background:blue; 
  width:150px;
  height:300px;
  left: calc(50% + 150px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g4vbampm/4/

Browser support for calc is pretty good, http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

If you need it to work in browsers that don’t support calc, you can also use a negative margin to offset the elements from the middle,

```
.left{
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: 150px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g4vbampm/7/

Comment: Thanks, this worked. A bit weird that the center part stats 8 pixels down for no reason, but a margin-top: -8 px solved it.

Comment: That’s due to the default margins/paddings of html/body that are applied via the browser stylesheet - those have no effect on fixed positioned elements, but they keep the middle element a bit from the top of course. If you don’t like that, then you should overwrite those in your stylesheet explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once

```css
.app{
    text-align:center;
}

.left{
  background:red;
  width:150px;
  height:300px;
  position:fixed;
  float:left;
  left:0px;
}

.center{
  background:green;
  width:calc(100% - 300px);
  width:-webkit-calc(100% - 300px);
  width:-moz-calc(100% - 300px);
  height:auto;
  float:left;
  margin-left:150px;
 
}

.right{
  background:blue; 
  width:150px;
  height:300px;
  position:fixed;
 float:left;
 right:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">

<div class="left">
menu1<br/>
menu2<br/>
menu3<br/>
</div>

<div class="center">
CONTENT<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>

a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
</div>

<div class="right">
menu1<br/>
menu2<br/>
menu3<br/>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Try It Should Be Responsive For Any Resolution Check Once

Comment: Thanks, but the menu is stretching with the window. Width should be fixed.

Comment: K I Updated Just now in my Snippet Check Once

Answer (score 0):

If you want to used fixed position for left and right divs even when u scroll than do like this.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
  }

.left,
.right {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.center {
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="left">
    content
  </div>

  <div class="center">
    content
    content
    contentcontent
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    contetn
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Remember, use * { margin: 0 } only if you didn't reset your html.

Comment: your solution is not cross browser solution

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
.app{
        text-align:center;
    }

    .left{
      position:fixed;
      background:red;
      width:150px;
      height:300px;
      left:0;
      float: left;
    }

    .center{
      position: relative;
      background:green;
      width:300px;
      height:auto;
      left: 140px;
      float: left;
    }

    .right{
      position: fixed;
      background:blue; 
      width:150px;
      height:300px;
      left: 445px;
      float: left;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9wnwL7rp/

Answer (score -1):

Try to use css `float` property. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp. But you have to split your main container into 3 columns. So `.left` class will have width 33.3% so on and so on. If you want some good html framework for grid system try to take a look on http://getbootstrap.com/ grid system